# Efficiently store and retrieve price points over time ranges

Tags: ssas, etl, business-intelligence, cube, powerpivot

We are loading data from a source that contains rates with date ranges. The rate seldom changes. E.g.

```
ProductId, SupplierId, CategoryId, Rate, ValidFrom, ValidTo
1, 2, 3, 4.0, 2014-01-01, 2014-06-30
```

This rate is valid for six months. The reporting requirement is to display average rates for flexible time ranges over products, suppliers, categories...

Therefore I joined the rates with the time dimension, resulting in a fact table like this:

```
ProductId, SupplierId, CategoryId, Rate, Date
1, 2, 3, 4.0, 2014-01-01
1, 2, 3, 4.0, 2014-01-02
... (approx. 180 rows for this one rate)
```

so there will be one rate per day. Since the rates are sometimes valid for a year or two, I am producing a large fact table with about 200 million rows and growing.

The cube loads in a couple of minutes and aggregates the data down to about 1.5 GB (while the datamart occupies about 20 GB). The cube query performance seems OK.

I could of course change the granularity, for example aggregate to a month. But the rates are daily rates, they do not change often but not necessarily on the first day of a month.

I just wanted to get opinions on the row proliferation the ETL process produces. Does it have a smell, are there better ways to get done what we need?

Comment: I'm not sure where the tipping point would be, but if the rates didn't change very often, I'd be inclined to just query the relational tables rather than try to put them in their own fact table.  Where rates relate to other facts, I would make the rate a dimension rather than a fact.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, Tab. I have no experience with direct sql access for facts. I just know the Rolap / Molap... scenarios, but in the end I get a cube as a data source for reporting. Could you hint me on how to include facts from an sql query into an SSAS cube?

Comment: I will post it as an answer with additional detail so it's easier to edit rather than create a long comment thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the tipping point would be, but if the rates didn't change very often, I'd be inclined to just query the relational tables rather than try to put them in their own fact table.

Meaning, if I just wanted to get the rates for a certain Product/Supplier/Category set over a range of dates, and I knew that the table was in the 1000-10000's, and not in the 100,000-1,000,000's, I would just run a straight sql query for the results, rather than getting it from a cube at all.

And by the table, I mean the table with the start/end dates for each rate, not the one where you have a row for every rate, every day.

If the relational table is indexed for my query, it should return plenty quickly.

Where rates relate to other facts, Sales for instance, I would make the rate a dimension rather than a fact.  That would be to answer queries like "what rate was in force when this sale took place?"

Comment: If users browse the OLAP cube with Excel Pivot, will they be able to use the rate measure coming from the sql query just as if it was a cube measure? I.e. is it possible to "mix" sql results and SSAS results within one MDX query? I may not be getting your idea in full or at least I don't know how to technically apply the sql query. In an application I would know how to do what you propose, but the cube must be accessible to typical reporting tools.

Comment: Well that's a good question.  Your original question didn't mention Excel.  I'm not that familiar with Excel Pivot, and I don't know if you can mix relational query results with cube data in Excel.   If that's a requirement that makes it absolutely necessary to have rate as a Measure in your cube, then the way you're already doing it is probably the best way.  I wouldn't be concerned about the row proliferation.  Just use partitioning if it gets obnoxious (I think 20 million rows is the recommended tipping point there).

Comment: Thanks Tab and sorry for not mentioning that requirement. I think what you suggested - using plain SQL for the data in question - is probably possible even when only accessing the cube, because a ROLAP cube will essentially do the same. So that would be worth checking, but for now your evaluation that my design is not completely bogus satisfies my question and I will check the sql part again once the performance is below requirements even with partitioning.